# Can a comment have an automatic format or marker to show the commenter is the OP?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments

When reading comments, especially on long posts with many answers, sometimes I have to scroll back up to the question to check if the commenter is the OP, to put the comment into context.

Could something such as a symbol beside the commenter's name automatically appear, to indicate when they are the OP?

Comment: The OP's comments should have the username highlighted in blue, what browser are you using?

Comment: This is **already implemented**. The OP of a question has their name displayed in blue on comments, both on the question and on any answers to their question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am a little confused.. Does it mean it was a bug or is this question "cannot reproduce"? Not that it matters of course. Was about to cv it

Comment: @suraj: it's a feature request, and moot because we already have a visual indicator. Unless the OP now provides screenshots that show that they can't see the change in colour (and haven't just not noticed it before) then there may be a bug report.

Comment: ok.. Thanks for the clarification @MartijnPieters

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is already a feature, the OP's comments should have a blue background on their username .

[image]

It's even true on answers

[image]

Comment: And so my comment should have my user name highlighted ... how embarrassing not to have realised this before. Thanks for pointing it out.